# Data not showing in Angular Material Table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am having trouble producing data with an angular material table.

This is the component

```
export class CertificateTableComponent {

  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any>;
  //certificates: ValueEntity[] = [];
  data: CertificateRow[] = [];
  columns: string[] = ['name', 'id', 'type', 'publicCertificate'];

  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static:true }) paginator: MatPaginator;

  constructor(private _integrationAccountService: integrationAccountService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this._integrationAccountService.getcertificates().subscribe(response => {
      //this.certificates = response.data;
      this.data = [];
      if (response.value) {
          for (let entity of response.value) {
              let row: CertificateRow = {
                  name: entity.name,
                  id: entity.id,
                  type: entity.type,
                  publicCertificate: entity.properties?.publicCertificate
              };
          }
      }

      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.data);
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

    })

  }
}
```

This is the table:

```
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row.name }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Id</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row.id }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="type">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Type</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row.type }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="publicCertificate">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Public Certificate</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row.publicCertificate }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columns;"></tr>

  </table>
```

When checking with in the console I can see the response values are correct but dataSource always appears empty. Not sure what I am missing when passing data to the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are code seems fine (at least for me) except that you forgot to add constructed object to `data array` list.

```
     this.data = [];
     if (response.value) {
          for (let entity of response.value) {
              let row: CertificateRow = {
                  name: entity.name,
                  id: entity.id,
                  type: entity.type,
                  publicCertificate: entity.properties?.publicCertificate
               };
               this.data.push(row);      // add here
           }
       }
```

Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: This has solved my issue, thanks for the help